# Display normal HTML elements on single page of Angular Material web app

Tags: html, css, angular, element

I have an Angular (6) web app that is themed and styled with Angular Material.

I wish to display a popup dialog that contains non-styled, standard HTML elements such as checkboxes, buttons and inputs.

I've got the dialog appearing properly but I'm unsure how to start adding non-styled, non-Material html elements.

My initial attempt was to simply add the raw element tag without any material directives but that didn't work as Material's baseline css destroys the default element style.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the `mat-modal` form Angular Material ?

Comment: @ХристиянХристов No, I'm using MatDialog

Answer (score 0):

I created a stackblitz that is using the Angular Material Popup dialog and it includes non-styled, standard HTML elements, you can view that here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csaqaq-vidddn

Just do your typical HTML `<button>submit</button>` and not the material tags `<button mat-button>Click me!</button>`

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't work for me; must be to do with the 3rd party theme I'm using (like I said in the question - I'd already tried just using normal html elements without any joy).  I actually got it working using an iframe.